# Backbone 0.9.9 validate model on create new Model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

After update to the new Backbone version 0.9.9 there is the problem that when I want to create a new model it always get into the validate function. E.g. I set "title" in defaults and "title":"" and in validate I want to check if there is a length.
If on startup the validate function is run, then there will always be a error.

What could I do?

Comment: having same experience..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could allow empty title in your validate method, or you always instantiate your models with values, e.g.: `new Model({ title: 'my title' })`

In the worse scenario, you can check if model is fetched or not, by example:

```
validate: function( attrs ) {
  if( this.fetched ) {
    if( !attrs.title.length ) { return "error!"; }
  }
}
```

Then, you would just have to setup `this.fetched` to true when you've get all your information and build your model correctly.

But the fact is that your `defaults` value should be in valid format from the start.

**edit after discution in comments**
You could probably also check the `hasChanged` function from `Backbone.model` to allow validation or not. For example:

```
validate: function( attrs ) {
  if( this.hasChanged() ) {
    if( !attrs.title.length ) { return "error!"; }
  }
}
```

This way, you'll skip the validation on initialization, and then, it'll only validate when you `set` new values.

Comment: But if the `defaults` are valid by default, how is one supposed to validate for required fields?

Comment: All validation don't need to be done in the model. For example, I wouldn't validate a form with my model `validate` method; this type of validation would be hold on my view.

Comment: On one hand there's that approach. On the other it would seem that the validation rules belong on the domain object for reusability, consistency etc. I feel like Backbone is making it really hard to "do the right thing". Then there's Backbone.Validation, which is built on the premise that you define the rules on the model (different config, though).

Comment: Yeah, I understand your point. Still, I found it more logic to always validate data to be put in your model. Maybe you could use `changedAttributes` or `hasChanged` in your validation function to allow invalid defaults.

Comment: I was going to open an issue about this on github, but it seems that they've already "closed the book" on this one, it seems: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/1930#issuecomment-11379527 - a shame, really.